# Question about coordinates from Google Earth Pro to ArcMap

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, google-earth

I have a project where I must georeference an archaeological site. I have only a picture from Google Earth on which there are drawn some tombs. I am trying to goereference the image but the picture is coming from an old version of Google Earth and thus the landscape (when I view it in a basemap) has changed a lot. Because of this I cannot find some certain points to georeference the picture. I managed to find old satellite photos from Google Earth Pro and find some points (some trees for example) and extract the coordinates. But, as a noob I am confused about the projections on ArcMap. I can't figure out what coordinate system Google Earth Pro uses in order to use the same with my layers on ArcMap and, in result, to locate the exact points and georeference my picture. Maybe this method is totally wrong but I don't know what else to do. I have no coordinates regarding the site, only this old satellite picture.

Comment: How are you bringing the points from Earth Pro into ArcMap?  Are you saving as a KML and then importing that into ArcMap?  No matter what method you use, you probably will need to set the coordinate system in ArcMap to WGS84 un-projected (ESP 4326), since that's what KML and Google Earth use.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i did. Thank you. I will try using the ESP 43267.